# Filter_all(any_vars()) Where am I going wrong?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 51 obs. of 20 variables called `test`. Like below:

```
X1 P1 P2 P3
A  1  0  5
B  3  9  0
C  5  0  0
D  1  0  0
```

I want to remove all rows where there are values under or equal to 1. So the resulting dataframe would  only have A,B,C rows.
I thought I cracked it using the below command:

```
test2 <- test %>% filter_all(any_vars(. > 2))
```

I also tried

```
test2 <- test %>% select(X1, P1:P3) %>% filter_all(any_vars(. > 2).
```

This doesn't remove any of the rows even though I can see rows have values under or equal to 1.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ .x > 1))
```

With a modified data set it returns:

```
  X1 P1 P2 P3
1  B  3  9  2
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(X1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), P1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 
1L), P2 = c(0L, 9L, 0L, 0L), P3 = c(5L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Here is another way of doing this with `purrr::pmap`:

- `pmap` is used for row-wise operations, here we capture each row of our data set in every iteration with `c(...)` while excluding the first variable `X1`
- Then I check if all of them are greater than `1`

```
df %>%
  filter(pmap_lgl(df[-1], ~ all(c(...) > 1)))

  X1 P1 P2 P3
1  B  3  9  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It  is not able to find 'if_all' even though I have 'dplyr'

Comment: I think you should update your package, since `if_all` and `if_any` are relatively new features on `dplyr`.

Comment: Nice use of `if_all` and great explanatio, As it is `all`, then `across` would also work

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very kind of you. Never used `across` in this situation you can add it so we learn that too.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can take help of `rowSums` -

```
res <- test[rowSums(test[-1] > 2) > 0, ]
res

#  X1 P1 P2 P3
#1  A  1  0  5
#2  B  3  9  2
#3  C  5  0  0
```